# Want ability to retract vote-to-close

Tags: feature-request

Occasionally I change my mind about the value of a question, or about which concern I have with it. We let folks retract/correct up or down votes (though we limit that on comments); we should have an undo capability on close votes, which are arguably more critical.

Answer (score 6):

You can already do this. Click on the close button again and select Retract Close Vote. I.e.

[image: Retract close vote]

Comment: I don't think the app offers that option, but will look again...

Comment: If you have a question about the app, make sure you use the appropriate tags to indicate that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @keshlam what app? iOS app or android app?

Comment: Android. It's a good start but some functionality is still obscure or missing.